# onsubmit gets triggered on every form field change

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement simple form which triggers API call on form submit in React.

It blows my mind as when trying the below code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import axios from 'axios';

var panelStyle = {
    'max-width': '80%',
    margin: '0 auto'
}

class DBInject extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.formHandler = this.formHandler.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      formFields: {Id: '',
      Name: '',
      Payment: "01-10-2019",
      Type: '',
      Value: 110,
      Cycle:'',
      Frequency:''
    }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
     <div>
    <div class="panel panel-primary" style={panelStyle}>
      <div class="panel panel-heading">React Forum - Register</div>
      <div class="panel panel-body">
        <form onsubmit={this.formHandler(this.state.formFields)}>
          <strong>Id:</strong> <br /> <input type="text" name="Id" placeholder="123" onChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)} value={this.state.formFields.Id} /> <br />
          <strong>Name:</strong> <br /> <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="me@example.com" onChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)} value={this.state.formFields.Name}/> <br />
          <strong>Cycle:</strong> <br /> <input type="text" name="Cycle" placeholder="me@example.com" onChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)} value={this.state.formFields.Cycle} /> <br />
          <strong>Frequency:</strong> <br /> <input type="text" name="Frequency"  onChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)} value={this.state.formFields.Frequency}/> <br />
          <strong>Type:</strong> <br /> <input type="text" name="Type" onChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)} value={this.state.formFields.Type} /> <br />
          <strong>Payment:</strong> <br /> <input type="date" name="Payment"  onChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)} value={this.state.formFields.Payment}/> <br />
          <strong>Value:</strong> <br /> <input type="number" name="Value"  onChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)} value={this.state.formFields.Value}/> <br /><br />
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Send to database</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    );
  }

  inputChangeHandler(e) {
    console.log(e);
   let formFields = {...this.state.formFields};
   formFields[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
   this.setState({
    formFields
   });
  };

  formHandler(formFields) {
    console.log(formFields);
    alert('This button does nothing.');
   axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:1880/api','', {headers:formFields})
     .then(function(response){
       console.log(response);
       //Perform action based on response
   })
     .catch(function(error){
       console.log(error);
       //Perform action based on error
     });
  }
}

export default DBInject
```

`formHandler` gets called every time `InputchangeHandler` gets called - which is not my intention.

Is there any other simpler way to do it in React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `setState` the component re-renders. Your `form` element is calling the function every time it re-renders. You need to make the following changes:

```
#Update onsubmit
<form onsubmit={this.formHandler.bind(this)}>

#Reference the formFields directly from the component's state
formHandler() {
const { formFields } = this.state;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more on React forms here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Make sure to reference state from inside the handler function rather than passing it in - as this will make your function re-render every state update.

Form element:

```
//make sure the "S" in submit is capitalized
<form onSubmit={this.formHandler}>

  ...Your Form Contents

</form>
```

Handler function:

```
formHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault() // stop propagation at the start

  // reference state from here with this.state like so:
  const { formFields } = this.state;

  ...Your handler code
}
```

Comment: Many thanks:-) Works like a charm now after these changes:-)